# Unable to mount an LVM Hard-drive after upgrade

Tags: mount, fstab, lvm

I imagine this is a basic gotcha ... but I can't see it.
I have a system with 2(physical) harddrives.

The boot system (/dev/sda) was running 10.04 & the second drive (/dev/sdb) was just a mounted filesystem.

I did a clean load of Ubuntu 12.04 overwriting /dev/sda (not an upgrade) & now cannot mount the second drive.
so I do not know what to enter it into the fstab ...
I had expected to use:

> /dev/sdb   /tera   ext4    defaults    0   2

But even manual mounting fails
 (I also have tried various "-t" options on the off chance!)

> sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /tera
>
> mount: wrong fs type, bad option,
>   bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>          In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>          dmesg | tail  or so

Output from disk queries indicate that it is  a Linux LVM & a healthy disk still.

> sudo lshw -C disk
>
> ```
>    *-disk:0
>    description: ATA Disk
>    product: WDC WD5000AACS-0
>    vendor: Western Digital
>    physical id: 0
>    bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
>    logical name: /dev/sda
>    version: 01.0
>    serial: WD-WCASU1401098
>    size: 465GiB (500GB)
>    capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
>    configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=00015a55
>    *-disk:1
>    description: ATA Disk
>    product: WDC WD10EADS-00L
>    vendor: Western Digital
>    physical id: 1
>    bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
>    logical name: /dev/sdb
>    version: 01.0
>    serial: WD-WCAU47836304
>    size: 931GiB (1TB)
>    capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
>    configuration: ansiversion=5
> ```
>
> sudo fdisk -l
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500106780160 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976771055 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00015a55
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sda1   *        2048   972580863   486289408   83  Linux
>   /dev/sda2       972582910   976769023     2093057    5  Extended
>   /dev/sda5       972582912   976769023     2093056   82  Linux swap /
>   Solaris
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> > Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
> >
> > /dev/sdb1               1  1953525167   976762583+  8e  Linux LVM

LVM doesn't appear to be an option for mount or fstab.

... and here's a Smart data Screenshot from Disk Utility.

Comment: Does the drive support NCQ? What is the status of Native Command Queuing (NCQ) on the drive in question?

Comment: Don't know, and not sure how that helps.

Comment: I can see "SMART data" for the disk in the Disk Utility GUI (It looks healthy).

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gSugw.png

Answer (score 7):

**Solution discovered hours later!**

This is a problem of LVM config not being preserved during the fresh install, and the install takes no interest in other disks in the system (*sigh*).

The clue for this came from:  http://linuxwave.blogspot.sg/2007/11/mounting-lvm-disk-using-ubuntu-livecd.html

(This mini-editor makes a mess of text output!)

- pvscan
- vgscan
- lvscan
- vgchange -a y

> root@argentine:/home/bruce# pvscan
>
> ```
>  PV /dev/sdb1   VG tera01   lvm2 [931.00 GiB / 0    free]
> Total: 1 [931.00 GiB] / in use: 1 [931.00 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
> ```
>
> root@argentine:/home/bruce# vgscan
>
> ```
> Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
> Found volume group "tera01" using metadata type lvm2
> ```
>
> root@argentine:/home/bruce# lvscan
>
> ```
> inactive          '/dev/tera01/teravol00' [931.00 GiB] inherit
> ```
>
> root@argentine:/home/bruce# vgchange -a y
>
> ```
> 1 logical volume(s) in volume group "tera01" now active
> ```
>
> root@argentine:/home/bruce# lvscan
>
> ```
> ACTIVE            '/dev/tera01/teravol00' [931.00 GiB] inherit
> ```
>
> root@argentine:/home/bruce# mount -t ext3 /dev/sdb1 /tera
>
> ```
> mount: /dev/sdb1 already mounted or /tera busy
> ```
>
> root@argentine:/home/bruce# mount -t ext3 /dev/tera01/teravol00 /tera
>
> root@argentine:/home/bruce# ls -l /tera
>
> ```
> total 32
> drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  4096 Jun  2  2008 export
> drwxrwxrwx. 5 root root  4096 Nov 15  2009 kept
> drwx------  2 root root 16384 May 16  2009 lost+found
> ```
>
> root@argentine:/home/bruce#

Bingo!!! (I really didn't want to dig them out of the backups!)

I then tried to add the following to  to /etc/fstab (for re-boot)

> /dev/tera01/teravol100     /tera   ext3    defaults    0   2

but that didn't work, so I finally used the GUI system-config-lvm to set it to mount on re-boot. (I think it did something in the background to also activate LVM on re-boot.)

- Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but it was because webmin with Ubuntu 12.04 wanted to mount my old lvm volume as an ext4 file system, instead of an ext3 system. When I changed the `fstab` mount command to ext3 it mounted correctly.

I note in your texts initially your command referenced ext4 and later ext3. Might your problem not have been the same as mine?