# Problem accessing external Ubuntu encrypted disc from Mint

Tags: boot, mount, encryption

First post as it seems I'm in a difficult position.

So I used to have a Ubuntu 14.04 system which crashed, meaning that it consistently tries to login after entering credentials, but nothing happens for hours.

So as I have my beloved files inside, I used a Mint live CD to access the drive and transfer my files to an external drive, but I'm not able to see the files.

I'm an entry level user, so knowledge of Linux systems is kind of limited.

So when I login through CD Mint I see the disk, try to mount/access it and after I get the password prompt, I type it and then it returns that media cannot be mounted and the disk is not visible after that at  "Computer".

The disk is a WD250 GB.

When typing from the Terminal ::

`sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 149.1 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000e8af2
Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 312580095 312078338 148.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 312580095 312078336 148.8G 83 Linux
```

Then when I `sudo mount /dev/sda /media`

```
mount: /dev/sda is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/sda is already mounted or /media busy
```

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

So I continue researching and found this post https://askubuntu.com/a/161457/573024 which granted me access to my data after all.

More detailed:: I try to open the encrypted disc with proper password and then it gives me cannot mount it and the disc is dissapeared.
I go to terminal and type vgchange -a y and disc is accessible.

I'm copying data to an external disk and data is accessible.